# php/js/jquery как правильно создать вложенный список из неправильного массива

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

В PHP получаю массив объектов. Каждый объект является либо родителем, либо потомком. Каждый объект имеет уникальный ID. 
Но у потомков имеется PARENT_ID - который соответствует ID его родителя.
Потомки и родители перемешаны в массиве и идут беспорядочно.
Задача как в PHP и/или JS получить из этого:

```
Array(
Array ( [ID] => 4 [PARENT_ID] => 0 )
Array ( [ID] => 8 [PARENT_ID] => 4)
Array ( [ID] => 9 [PARENT_ID] => 3)
Array ( [ID] => 6 [PARENT_ID] => 4)
Array ( [ID] => 3 [PARENT_ID] => 0 )
Array ( [ID] => 2 [PARENT_ID] => 0 )
)
```

ЭТО:

```
  <ul id="ID-4" data-parent="4">
<li id="ID-8" data-child="4"></li>
<li id="ID-6" data-child="4"></li>
</ul>

  <ul id="ID-3" data-parent="3">
<li id="ID-8" data-child="3"></li>
</ul>

  <ul id="ID-2" data-parent="2">
</ul>
```

Ответ у меня получился таким. Это рабочий вариант. Если кому нужно, пользуйтесь.

```
  $db = array("Наш массив с подмассивами");
foreach($db as $key => $ar)
{
if(!$ar["PARENT_ID"]){
 echo "<ul id='ID-".$ar["ID"]."' data-parent='".$ar["ID"]."' style='background:#aaa;'>".$ar["NAME"];
 $db2 = array("тот же самый массив с подмассивами в новой переменной");
 foreach($db2 as $key2 => $ar2)
{
if($ar2["PARENT_ID"]==$ar["ID"]){
echo "<li id='ID-".$ar2["ID"]."'  data-child='".$ar2["PARENT_ID"]."' style='background:#afa;margin:20px auto;'>".$ar2["NAME"]."</li>";
}
}echo "</ul>";}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чуваки, я не знаю кто из вас круче. Я в PHP ни бум бум. Первый вариант почти то что нужно. Но у меня не получилось его применить в реальности, так как не знаю как пихнуть туда новые поля с текстом. Например каждый подмассив получает еще
 [TEXT] => ["text"] и много полей, вроде NAME и прочего

ЗАБЫЛ ДОБАВИТЬ важную вещь! Массив формируется не с теми цифрами которые даны в примере. ID и PARENT_ID могут со временем меняться. Есстественно надо писать такой код, который не будет требовать переделки каждый раз при изменении элементов массива

Второй вариант только увидел и обязательно попробую.

Самолично у меня получилось сейчас за 15 минут выразить то что надо таким образом:

```
  $db = array("Наш массив с подмассивами");
  foreach($db as $key => $ar)
{
   if(!$ar["PARENT_ID"]){
     echo "<ul style='background:#aaa;'>".$ar["NAME"];
     $db2 = array("тот же самый массив с подмассивами в новой переменной");
     foreach($db2 as $key2 => $ar2)
{
if($ar2["PARENT_ID"]==$ar["ID"]){
echo "<li style='background:#afa;margin:20px auto;'>".$ar2["NAME"]."</li>";
}
}echo "</ul>";}
}
```

Этот код может и не такой крутой как у вас, но делает то что надо и очень понятный. В моем конкретном случае этот код предназначен для битрикса, и в данном случае необходимо вывести родителей как SELECT а потомков как OPTION
К сожалению в битриксе при выгрузке массива он всех потомков располагает на том же уровне что и родителей. Из-за этого их не пихнуть в виде OPTION или даже UL>LI

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
$array = Array(
  Array('ID' => 4, 'PARENT_ID' => 0),
  Array('ID' => 8, 'PARENT_ID' => 4),
  Array('ID' => 9, 'PARENT_ID' => 3),
  Array('ID' => 6, 'PARENT_ID' => 4),
  Array('ID' => 3, 'PARENT_ID' => 0),
  Array('ID' => 2, 'PARENT_ID' => 0)
);
$arr = Array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
  if(empty($arr[$array[$i]['PARENT_ID']])){
    $arr[$array[$i]['PARENT_ID']] = Array();
  };
};
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
  array_push($arr[$array[$i]['PARENT_ID']], $array[$i]['ID']);
};
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
  echo '<ul id="ID-'.array_keys($arr)[$i].'" data-parent="'.array_keys($arr)[$i].'">';
  for($a = 0; $a < count($arr[array_keys($arr)[$i]]); $a++){
    echo '<li id="ID-'.$arr[array_keys($arr)[$i]][$a].'" data-child="'.array_keys($arr)[$i].'"></li>';
  };
  echo '</ul>';
};
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {
  var arr = [{id: 4, parent_id: 0}, {id: 8, parent_id: 4}, {id: 9, parent_id: 3}, {id: 6, parent_id: 4}, {id: 3, parent_id: 0}, {id: 2, parent_id: 0}]
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if($('ul#ID-'+arr[i].parent_id).length !== 0){
       $('ul#ID-'+arr[i].parent_id).append('<li id="ID-'+arr[i].id+'" data-child="'+arr[i].parent_id+'"></li>');
    }else{
       $('body').append('<ul id="ID-'+arr[i].parent_id+'" data-parent="'+arr[i].parent_id+'"><li id="ID-'+arr[i].id+'" data-child="'+arr[i].parent_id+'"></li></ul>');
    };
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если просто упорядочить массив для дальнейшей выдачи без вычислений то можно так:

```
$struct = [];
$arr = [
    ['ID' => 4 , 'PARENT_ID' => 0] , 
    ['ID' => 5 , 'PARENT_ID' => 4] , 
    ['ID' => 9 , 'PARENT_ID' => 3] , 
    ['ID' => 6 , 'PARENT_ID' => 4] , 
    ['ID' => 3 , 'PARENT_ID' => 0] , 
    ['ID' => 2 , 'PARENT_ID' => 0] , 
];

array_map(function($el)use(&$struct , $arr){
        $parent = $el['PARENT_ID'];
        if(!$struct[$parent]){
            $struct[$parent] = array_filter($arr , function($el)use($parent){
                return $el['PARENT_ID']==$parent;
            });
        } 
} , $arr);



print_r($struct);
```

на выходе получим сгруппированный по `PARENT_ID` массив:

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 4
                    [PARENT_ID] => 0
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 3
                    [PARENT_ID] => 0
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [PARENT_ID] => 0
                )

        )...
```